# PHP implements ArrayAccess

Tags: php, magic-methods, arrayaccess

I have two Classes viz foo & Bar

```
class bar extends foo
{

    public $element = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

and the Class foo goes as

```
class foo implements ArrayAccess
{

    private $data = [];
    private $elementId = null;

    public function __call($functionName, $arguments)
    {
        if ($this->elementId !== null) {
            echo "Function $functionName called with arguments " . print_r($arguments, true);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        $this->elementId = $id;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->data[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->data[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            unset($this->data[$offset]);
        }
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        if (!$this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            $this->$offset = new foo($offset);
        }
    }
}
```

i want that when i run the below piece of code:

```
$a = new bar();
$a['saysomething']->sayHello('Hello Said!');
```

should return **Function sayHello Called with arguments Hello Said!** from foo's __call magic method.

Here, i want to say is **saysomething** should be passed in **$this->elementId** from foo's **__construct** function and **sayHello** should be taken as *method* and **Hello Said** should be taken as *parameters* for sayHello Function which would be rendered from **__call magic method**.

Also, need to chain methods like:

```
$a['saysomething']->sayHello('Hello Said!')->sayBye('Good Bye!');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should change `foo::offsetGet()` to this:

```
public function offsetGet($offset)
{
    if (!$this->offsetExists($offset)) {
        return new self($this->elementId);
    } else {
        return $this->data[$offset];
    }
}
```

It returns an instance of itself if there's no element at the given offset.

That said, `foo::__construct()` should be called from `bar::__construct()` as well *and* be passed a value other than `null`:

```
class bar extends foo
{

    public $element = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(42);
    }
}
```

**Update**

To chain calls, you need to return the instance from `__call()`:

```
public function __call($functionName, $arguments)
{
    if ($this->elementId !== null) {
        echo "Function $functionName called with arguments " . print_r($arguments, true);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: amazingly effective! Thanks a ton @Jack!

Comment: @Guns You're welcome; do note that `$bar['saysomething']` doesn't return a `bar` object but a `foo` object.

Comment: thanks!. This works perfectly fine, however, when i chain methods it does not work. I am trying `$a['saysomething']->sayHello['Hello Said!]->sayBye('Good Bye!');`. How do i achieve this?

Comment: @Guns In that case, `__call()` must `return $this;` instead of `return true;`. Updated answer.

Comment: Wonderful! i wish i could give you 15-20 upvotes for this! Thanks a Ton @Jack